# Show count data in Yii Gridview from two models

Tags: php, yii

I have 2 tables, servers and ip, in ip table I am saving `server_id`. 
Now I want to show on server listing page how many total ips related to one server?

MY Server model code:

```
   class Server extends CActiveRecord {

        public function relations(){
     return array('ipmodel'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'IpManager', 'server_id'),
        );
       }
     }
```

My CGridView Code:

```
     array( 
        'header' => 'IP Count',
        'value' => 'count($data->ipmodel)',
     ),
```

It is showing only **1** but there are so many ips against to one server!
How I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change relation!

```
      'ipmodel'=>array(self::HAS_MANY, 'IpManager', 'server_id')
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use inbuilt `STAT` relation of Yii framework:

**Relation:**

```
'ipmodelcount'=>array(self::STAT, 'IpManager', 'server_id')
```

**In grid view use it directly:**

```
array( 
  'header' => 'IP Count',
  'value' => '$data->ipmodelcount',
),
```

**Explaination:**

why use `STAT` relation for count?

`HAS_MANY` will load all related model's data while `STAT` relation run count query on server for related data. So using `STAT` will take less execution time to provide desire result.